# Calling App component synchronously in ionic3 / angular5

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework

My app component makes an HTTP call to get data that is required by other components to work well.

- When running `http://myapp/` everything works fine, since app component is called, and I use redirection to another component *after* the HTTP call has succeeded.
- However, when running `http://myapp/#/some-page` (using deeplinks), it seems app component is called in parallel of `SomePage` component. That way, `SomePage` tries to access data that does not exist yet, and it raises an error.

How could I force Ionic to wait my HTTP call is done before loading the component?

Note that I don't want to call a service in every component's `onInit` method, that would be a dirty solution to me, since I have many components.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Comment: Hi @Zentoaku. Sounds very interesting and related tu my problem, however, since I use Ionic, I don't use angular router for navigation.